# Passing googlemapsv3 through web sockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, socket.io

Is it possible to pass a googlemap through a web socket like this? (from client)

```
var mapOptions = {
            center: pathCoordinates[0],
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);

 $(function(){
     socket.emit('smap', pathCoordinates, data, gmap);
 });
```

I am trying to pass my map to the server side code where it can use it to plot new markers on it. I'm getting this error with the way it's currently set up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Comment: Wait what? What is your server code trying to do? Server code won't plot things on a map. It can only send you data that the client JS code can then manage and add to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing objects via web-sockets, the object gets converted into a JSON string. The particular error `Converting circular structure to JSON` is due to the object `gmap` containing circular references, which `JSON.stringify` does not support.

Furthermore, JSON does not support functions, so even if you could pass the `gmap` object to the server, calling `gmap.doSomething` wont work, as the functions are not preserved.

A better solution would be to pass marker data to the client, and have the client plot it on the map:

```
socket.on('data', function(markerData){
    map.doSomething(markerData);
});
```